# ¿Como puedo hacer INNER JOIN CON 4 TABLAS CON ALIAS?

Tags: join, inner

hice una consulta de INNER JOIN con dos tablas, pero quiero agregarle dos mas, les muestro mi codigo, porque no me sale, espero me puedan ayudar!

```
SELECT A.nocuenta, A.nombre_alumno, A.ape_paternoalum, A.ape_maternoalum, A.curp_alum, A.correo_alum, A.telefono_alum, A.ID_Edocivil, A.fechanacimiento_alum, 
L.Codigo_postal, L.Municipio, L.Estado, L.Colonia, L.numdom_alum, L.localidad_alum, L.calledom_alum
FROM alumno AS A INNER JOIN codigo_postal AS L ON 
A.ID_codigopostal = L.ID_codigopostal
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código con el que has intentado y qué es lo que _no te sale_?  Es decir, hay un error, o no da el resultado correcto, o qué es lo que pasa con ese código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vas por buen camino combina mas INNER JOIN con AS y la relaciona de las tablas. En este ejemplo utilizo de ejemplo tabla3 y tabla4 con el alias de T3 y T4. Cambia esos nombres por las tablas que quieres relacionar.

```
SELECT A.nocuenta,
A.nombre_alumno,
A.ape_paternoalum,
A.ape_maternoalum,
A.curp_alum, 
A.correo_alum, 
A.telefono_alum, 
A.ID_Edocivil, 
A.fechanacimiento_alum, 
L.Codigo_postal,
L.Municipio, 
L.Estado, 
L.Colonia, 
L.numdom_alum,
L.localidad_alum, 
L.calledom_alum, 
T3.variable, 
T4.variable2
FROM alumno AS A INNER JOIN codigo_postal AS L 
ON A.ID_codigopostal = L.ID_codigopostal 
INNER JOIN tabla3 AS T3 
ON L.ID_codigopostal = T3.variable 
INNER JOIN tabla4 AS T4 
ON T3.variable = T4.variable2
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ayudo a resolver mi problema, gracias!!